# How can I combine the separate Video Files in Twilio-Video room into one?

Tags: twilio, video-recording, twilio-video

By enabling the RecordVideoParticpants to true,I am able to record the VideoRoom in my Twilio Account but it is getting saved as separate Media files with different Video and Audio entities.
Is there a way to combine and encode it into on single Video-with -audio.

Thank you.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/recordings-resource
I am following the above mentioned docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the reason for the [Compositions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/compositions-resource) API.

> The Twilio Recording Composition API lets you transcode and combine
> the individual Track Recordings stored by the Twilio Video Recordings
> API.

Comment: Yes,i did go through it but I am facing trouble to set-up the composition hook.  I manually setup the composition API and was able to  get a single media file but I want to automate the process.

Comment: May I know how composition hooks work when we don't even Provide the Room SID?  It just needs Twilio credentials and I am confused